# When the magento2.4 order status changes to completed, can I perform an event to process one of my tasks

Tags: magento2

When the magento2.4  order status changes to completed, can I perform an event to process one of my tasks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such event which observes specific order status complete. Still, you can try with **sales_order_state_change_before** or **sales_order_save_after** events.

> Solution #1: `sales_order_save_after` event:

**Observer/SalesOrderAfterSave.php**

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    if ($order instanceof \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel) {
       if($order->getState() == 'complete') {
            //Your code here
       }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

> Solution #2: `sales_order_state_change_before` event:

**Observer/SalesOrderStateChangeBefore.php**

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
    if ($transport->getState() == "complete") {
        //Your code here
    }
    return $this;
}
```

> Solution #3 You can try using **Plugin** also:

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="order_state_plugin"
                type="Company\Module\Model\Plugin\OrderStatePlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**OrderStatePlugin.php**

```
public function afterSave(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
    $result
) {
    if($result->getState() == Order::STATE_COMPLETE) {
        ......
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: I use the sales_order_save_after event and sometimes I miss some orders.
Can I use the sales_order_invoice_save_after event? The action I'm going to perform is when the order status changes to completed.

Comment: yes, *sales_order_invoice_save_after* should work.

Comment: Thank you,it work!

Comment: @sqy If it worked, could you please accept my answer?